# Measurable set indicator functions - need clarification on a book's statement

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

A book I'm reading says the following about indicator functions $\chi_A$ :

[image]

But unless I'm missing something, how can that that be? If $B$ is for example the set $(-2,2)$, $1 \in B$, but since $B$ contains both $0$ and $1$, $\chi_A^{-1}(B) = \{x \in A\} \cup \{x \not \in A\} = S \neq A$.  Similarly, if $B$ is, say, the set $(-1, 0.5)$, then even though $1 \not \in B$, $\chi_A^{-1}(B)= \{x \not \in A\} \neq \{\emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. The statement should be

$$\chi_A^{-1}(B) = \begin{cases}
\emptyset & 0, 1 \not\in B\\
A & 0 \not\in B, 1 \in B\\
S\setminus A & 0 \in B, 1 \not\in B\\
S & 0, 1 \in B.
\end{cases}$$